# How can I force router-view to update if the URL changes

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a path that shows a user profile and the path is `website.com/user/38`. If I click on my own profile then the path changes to say `website.com/user/39` but the view does not change and I still see the profile of user `38`. The link to my profile is just a `router-link`:

```
<router-link
    :to="'/user/' + loggedUser"
    @click="hideSub"><li>
        <img src="../assets/img/user.png" />Profile
    </li></router-link
>
```

If the path changes completely like to the home page then it works but not if path contains a variable.

Here is the user's path in the router's index file:

```
    {
        path: "/user/:id",
        name: "user",
        component: () => import("@/views/ProfileView.vue"),
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true,
        },
    },
```

Here is the code that fetches the profile data:

```
    try {
        let userdata = await axios.get("/api/v1/user/" + userID);
        user.value = userdata.data;
        if (user.value.profile != null) {
            userprofile.value = userdata.data.profile;
            home.value = userdata.data.home_address;
            username.value = userdata.data.username;
            document.title =
                userprofile.value.first_name +
                " " +
                userprofile.value.last_name +
                " | site";
            var birthdate = new Date(userprofile.value.birthdate);
            var month = birthdate.toLocaleString("default", { month: "long" });
            var day = birthdate.getDate();
            var bday = day + " " + month;
            birthday.value = bday;
        } else {
            userprofile.value = {};
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error) {
            if (error.response.status == 404) {
                router.push({ path: "/not-found", replace: true });
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I force the view to update if the path changes, without having to refresh the whole page?

Comment: where is the code that takes id param, fetch data from server and update the page. Please provide the complete code.

Answer (score 1):

This was a common problem with router-link in Vue. The router-view component does not rerender when the route parameters change, even when the URL does.

There are a few possible solutions to this issue:

1. You can use key attribute on router-view, which informs Vue to use different instance of component on same path navigation.

   ```
   <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
   ```
2. You can add props as true property to your route definition. So that whenever path param changes, the props change and trigger a rerender.

   ```
   {
     path: '/user/:userId',
     props: true,
     name: 'user',
     component: () => import('../views/UserProfile.vue')
   }
   ```
3. You can also use `beforeRouteUpdate` In-Component Gaurd. Reference: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

Comment: I tried all of these and none of them worked.